# How do I get my dog to stop peeing in the house when he has a doggie door?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training, anxiety

I have recently had to go back to work leaving my 9 year old Schnoodle all alone for 9-10 hours a day. Every day when I come home he is excited to see me then lays in his bed once I come in the house. (I'm thinking he knows that he did something wrong)  He has a doggie door and a fenced in yard to go in and out.  I should add that this dog was dropped off along side the road about 7 years ago so his age is a guesstimate from the vet.

Please help, I feel so guilty for leaving him as it is...

Comment: Hi Shelley! Is it many pees? Has there been a change in his drinking habits? Does he seem to be peeing more than usual?

Comment: Related: [8 year old boxer pees in his crate every time I leave](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9738/8-year-old-boxer-pees-in-his-crate-every-time-i-leave)

Comment: Have you had your vet check for stones in the bladder? My mom's dog started peeing while she was out with no lack of letting her dog out often. Her dog ended up with a really nasty pointy stone in her bladder. They had to surgically remove it. Also check for signs of a UTI.

Comment: Hi!  It is only 1 pee and not everyday.

Comment: Has anything changed in your household? new people, new pets. Some dogs act out this way with change. Have you noticed any incontinence? (ex. leaking/dribbling urine)

Comment: I used to be home all day with him,  just recently went back to work.  The first couple weeks he was ok and now this....